# Progress bar to load same speed as div's

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

On my progress bar I am trying to make it so it detects the div loading speed.

What I am trying to achieve if div is fast loading then will go to 100 % very quick. But progress bar should load as fast as the div loads.

**Question:** How can I make my progress bar load the speed that the div loads at.

## View my codepen example [click to view](http://codepen.io/riwakawebsitedesigns/pen/yNEBPW/)

Java Script

```
setTimeout(function(){

$('.progress .progress-bar').each(function() {

var me = $(this);
var perc = me.attr("data-percentage");

var current_perc = 0;

var progress = setInterval(function() {
if (current_perc>=perc) {
    clearInterval(progress);
} else {
    current_perc +=1;
    me.css('width', (current_perc) + '%');
}

me.text('Page Loading ' + (current_perc) + ' %');

}, 50);

});

},300);
```

HTML

```
<div class="container big-space">
    <div class="progress progress-striped active">
        <div class="progress-bar" style="width: 0%;" data-percentage="100"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container big-space">
<div class="well">
<h4>Sample Div</h4>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You want to visualize the rendering of your divs? I don't think that the human eye is able to see this. You'll commonly just haven an "always filled" progress bar.

Comment: @OddDev: I think its safe to assume the OPs intent is to load `<div>` elements from AJAX queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the transition and animation classes from the css:

```
.progress-bar.active, .progress.active .progress-bar {
    -webkit-animation: none;
    animation: none;
}
.progress-bar {
    -webkit-transition : none;
    transition : none;
}
```

You could also do this to make the animation more smooth:

```
.progress-bar {
    transition: width .05s ease;
}
```

Anyway notice, that the 0.05s equals your interval.

See your adapted example here: [codepen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/waXdzy)